# Loop Through First Column (Attribute) of Each Table from SQLite Database with Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm writing a utility to help analyze SQLite database consistencies using Python. Manually I've found some inconsistencies so I thought it would be helpful if I could do these in bulk to save time. I set out to try this in Python and I'm having trouble.

Let's say I connect, create a cursor, and run a query or two and end up with a result set that I want to iterate through. I want to be able to do something like this (list of tables each with an ID as the primary key):

```
# python/pseudocode of what I'm looking for
for table in tables:
    for pid in pids:
        query = 'SELECT %s FROM %s' % (pid, table)
        result = connection.execute(query)
        for r in result:
            print r
```

And that would yield a list of IDs from each table in table list. I'm not sure if I'm even close.

The problem here is that some tables have a primary key called `ID` while others `TABLE_ID`, etc. If they were all `ID`, I could select the IDs from each but they're not. This is why I was hoping to find a query that would allow me to select only the first column or the key for each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the columns of a table, execute [PRAGMA table_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) as a query.
The result's `pk` column shows which column(s) are part of the primary key:

```
> CREATE TABLE t(
>     other1 INTEGER,
>     pk1    INTEGER,
>     other2 BLOB,
>     pk2    TEXT,
>     other3 FLUFFY BUNNIES,
>     PRIMARY KEY (pk1, pk2)
> );
> PRAGMA table_info(t);
cid  name    type            notnull  dflt_value  pk
---  ------  --------------  -------  ----------  --
0    other1  INTEGER         0                    0 
1    pk1     INTEGER         0                    1 
2    other2  BLOB            0                    0 
3    pk2     TEXT            0                    2 
4    other3  FLUFFY BUNNIES  0                    0
```